# Layout: inflating compound view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

In my small demo app, I'm showing the camera preview on a SurfaceView. Works fine. But now I want to use a compound XML for the inner preview, so that I can render for example some text onto the camera picture. The layout on screen is:

[image]

```
class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }
```

The preview is created in the main activity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    Camera mCamera;
    int numberOfCameras;
    int cameraCurrentlyLocked;
    int defaultCameraId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
```

The simple XML for the main activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity" >

</FrameLayout>
```

So far so good. But now I added a camera_preview.xml which also includes the SurfaceView that was created in code before.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/renderingView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="blabla" />

</FrameLayout>
```

When I then change to constructor of the class CameraPreview ...

```
CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    String inflaterService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater li;
    li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(inflaterService);
    li.inflate(R.layout.camera_preview, this, true);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.renderingView);

    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
```

The problem is, that the resulting screen is just white and I don't see the preview neither the text. But I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.